# I cant continue after Scanf in MPICH2

Tags: c, mpi, wrapper, mpich, mpiexec

So I have a program which divides an array to equal arrays for slave machines. Im basicly using MPI_Scatter to do it. I have also a variable which decides what process will happen to these arrays. (like <0 - Sum> <1 - Min> <2 - Avg> <3 - Max>) So in my code in master section i have to take a number from user and send it to slaves. But after scanf program is just hanging. I am using vs 2015 and MPIEXEC wrapper.

```
if (MASTER == rank) //MASTER
    {
        printf("Yapilacak islem(0: Sum, 1: Min, 2: Avg, 3: Max): ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf_s("%d", &opID);

        ...

        for (int to = 1; to < size; to++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&opID, 1, MPI_INT, to, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }


    else //SLAVES
    {
        MPI_Recv(&opID, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
```

So after i enter a number it does not continue. Picture at the below.

[MPIEXEC wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do5JW.png)

Comment: Have you tried using GDB (or equivalent debugger)? I think you may be assuming that the code hangs on scanf, and not any of the code in the (...) section.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the MPI library was interfering with `stdin`.  Try changing the operation code to a command-line argument, or reading it before `MPI_Init`.  Also try using `fgets` to read an entire line, rather than `scanf` which won't consume anything after the number (e.g. the newline from the user pressing RETURN).  Incidentally, the Annex K `_s`-suffix functions are nonportable, implemented as specified by literally nobody (not even Microsoft, who invented them!) and don't even solve the problem they were intended to solve! Don't use them.

Comment: Yes code hangs on scanf, the code in (...) works perfectly if i do for example opID=2. I have no idea what is GDB.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: How can you know for a fact that it hangs on scanf if you have not used a debugger? Not trying to be argumentative... assumptions are a programmer's worst enemy. Also I agree with zwol, scanf_s is non-standard and it's generally bad practice to use non-portable functions. Have you tried other methods of getting user input? Also I'm not entirely sure if scanf is thread-safe in an MPI context. A question: do all ranks read from the same stdin?